# Error: 'reflect-metadata shim is required' when upgrading to Webpack 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, webpack, webpack-2

My team and I are trying to upgrade our code base to Webpack 2 and we are stuck with these two errors :

'Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators' & 'Cannot read property 'isDefaultChangeDetectionStrategy' of undefined'

We are working with the [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter), are up to date with RC5, and are trying to make this update.

We believe the error is coming from the polyfills.browser.ts file, in which we have this code:

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-set';
import 'core-js/es6/typed';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
// see issue https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/709
// import 'core-js/es6/promise';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

// Typescript emit helpers polyfill
import 'ts-helpers';

if ('production' === ENV) {
  // Production


} else {
  // Development

  Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

  require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');

}
```

Also, our webpack.common.js entry obj inside module.exports looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    {...},
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.browser.ts',
        'main': './src/main.browser.ts'
     },
     {...}
 }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this will be of any help but I had the exakt same problem, though I'm using the Angular CLI webpack beta 11 (NG RC5). While updating the CLI I failed to see that main.ts should have

```
import './polyfills.ts';
```

at the top. So I guess no polyfills was loaded, the reflect error just happened to be the first in line.

Comment: My import is working fine and I am still getting this error